# Debugging env vars from ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, environment-variables, sh

I'm writing a script and an application for an embedded board with linux - no X, only console. The only way to reach the target is via ssh, I don't have a monitor connected.

The script should export a couple of env vars which will be used by the application. I know I have to source the script to do this, but I'm in trouble to debug this because I don't know how to check if the script works from ssh.

Trivial solutions are:

- test the script in another system
- launch a debugging application to check the env vars and print a file
- etc...

I just wonder if there is a way to use ssh to do this. It's a curiosity to learn something new, the workarounds are known!

Example of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export MY_VAR="blablabla"
exit 0
```

the actual script is of course more complex, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide example of your script so it is hard to understand what are you trying to achieve. Anyway you should know that exported variables are visible only in current ssh session and its children. For example:

**ssh -t user@remotehost "export TEST=test && echo \$TEST"** - output is 'test'
**ssh -t user@remotehost "export TEST=test" && ssh -t user@remotehost "echo \$TEST"** - ouput is blank
If you want to define vars permanently do this in .bashrc or .bash_profile

Comment: Added the example as requested. Your solution works because you're exporting the variables directly as a command. But that should not work (I apologize, I cannot try until this afternoon) launching the script. You have to source the script, which will close the ssh connection when it ends...

Comment: Is the script located on source host or on remote host? How do you run it?

Comment: The script is located on the target (remote host). A Qt5 C++ application will run it.

Comment: Perhaps I found the problem. For some reasons the script which actually was on the target had an "exit 0" at the end (I've updated the initial example for coherence). Launching the script was ok, but sourcing it led to close the shell or the SSH connection - here my question!